# Michael Hartl's tutorial - ssl configuration - using elastic beanstalk - how to revert back to http?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am going over Michael Hartl's amazing tutorial, however I am using Elastic Beanstalk instead of Heroku.

On chapter 7 - we change the production.rb file as so:

```
SampleApp::Application.configure do

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security,
  # and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

end
```

Which then doesn't work with Elastic Beanstalk. The browser cannot connect to server. I have tried to comment out the line again. I have also tried to set

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

And now I cannot get the app to work anymore. Even reverting back to a version prior to the ssl change does not work.

Clearly some other file has changed. How do I get it back to a working app? I do not want to add the ssl certificate at this time (maybe later).

Thanks,

Sam

EDIT -- I can totally get to the app on my local machine. I cannot get to the version deployed on Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are unable to get to the app on your local machine through `rails s`.  Some people have overcome this issue through clearing their browsers cache.  I had this issue and the only fix is to use a thin client instead.

Add thin to your Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
    ....
    gem 'thin'
end
```

Install it:

```
bundle install
```

And then instead of running `rails s` use:

```
thin start --ssl
```

You should be able to access your app on your local machine again.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisBarthol - but my issue is once the app is deployed. Everything is working fine when I do `rails s`

Comment: Ah yes, then setting it false should work, I believe commenting it out sets it back to its default which is false.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by:

commenting out

```
 config.force_ssl = true
```

And rebuilding the environment on Elastic Beanstalk - Rebuilding the environment should be done with caution since it kills the database instance.

Happy to have it fixed!